# How to cast a value to long before aggregating it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2017, ef-core-2.1

As of EF core 2.1.4, if we cast an `int` value to `long` or `long?` before aggregation (maybe to avoid arithmetic overflow), this cast does not affect the generated query and the overflow happens anyway.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfCoreBugs
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(dbContext.Payments.Sum(x => (long?)x.Amount));
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=EfCoreBugs;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
      }
      public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payment
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

The genrated query is:

```
SELECT SUM([x].[Amount])
FROM [Payments] AS [x]
```

is there any way to fix this overflow problem? (Other than changing the datatype of `Amount` to `long`)

Comment: `dbContext.Payments.Select(x => (long)x.Amount).Sum();` ? does this work, just a guess

Comment: @TheGeneral No, still the same query is created. I also tried: `dbContext.Payments.Select(x => new { A = (long?)x.Amount }).Sum(z => z.A)` and failed.

Comment: also try `Convert.ToInt64(x.Amount)` it may or may not work

Comment: Of course, a workaround is to do the sum outside of the database (of course with possibly serious implications on performance), as in `dbContext.Payments.Select(x => x.Amount).AsEnumerable().Sum(x => (long?)x)`. But I think you want the sum to be done on the DB.

Comment: @TheGeneral `Convert.ToInt64(x.Amount)` translates to `SELECT SUM(CONVERT(bigint, [x].[Amount])) FROM [Payments] AS [x]` and runs without overflow. Can you please write it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, all good. :)

Comment: Yeah it was a total jag and luck

Comment: Sometimes that total jag and luck can save or waste many hours! Good guess, thank you.

Comment: If that code does not work then log a bug against EF on GitHub. The cast to long should not be ignored.

Comment: @usr yes, I've already created this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13885)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Convert.ToInt64(x.Amount)`

it may translate to

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(bigint, [x].[Amount])) FROM [Payments] AS [x]
```

and run without overflow

For future readers. this really depends on the *ORM* and it may not work in all cases

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If the `[Payments]` table contains no rows (or if `[Amount] is null` in all of the rows, for a column that allows null) the generated SQL will produce `null`, while the C# variable has type `long` which does not support `null`. Will you see `0` in C# in that case?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i wondered this myself, however i guess you could just check for null in the query if worst comes to worst

Comment: Yeah, but it is still interesting. Within the .NET Framework itself, `Convert.ToInt64((object)null)` will succeed and return `0L`. This overload is used if you put in an `int?` with `HasValue` false into `Convert.ToInt64(·)`. But I do not have EF just here, so I have not tested what happens there.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yeah it is, I'm on my phone aawell so I can't test it either